# How to implement UITableView with multiple columns and sideways scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview, horizontal-scrolling

I'm thinking about how I could achieve this kind of UITableView: http://snapplr.com/c1x5
So it has multiple (separately selectable) columns in it which also differ in width. Apart from that it can also scroll sideways to see programs which broadcast later on the day.

Now, I'd like to know how you would implement this kind of feature. A scrollview wouldn't be enough, it has to somehow load newer data. And of course you need to be able to know what column in the cell has been selected.

Hope to hear some thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

That is a custom view.

It's possible it could be a table view, with heavily customised cells, but that would have been a **hell** of a lot of work to get it scroll horizontally too.

It's more likely that it's a scroll view with a custom grid view type class that have support for arbitrary grid cell widths...

I'm sure if you write something like this you'll have a lot of interested people.

Answer (score 3):

I just updated [`MDSpreadView`](https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadViewDemo), which is basically a `UITableView` that works both horizontally and vertically, floating headers and all, with an API very similar to `UITableView`.